# How to add padding to html content using Jsoup?

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview, jsoup

I am using the Jsoup library to parse HTML content. I am using the following code to add style to my code tags.

```
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html_open);
            doc.append(content);
            doc.append(html_close);
            webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView1.setInitialScale(getScale());
            webView1.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            webView1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            webView1.setWebViewClient(
                    new WebViewClient() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                            String javascriptCode = "javascript:";
                            javascriptCode+="var elements=document.querySelectorAll(\"code\");";
                            javascriptCode+="var parent;";
                            javascriptCode+="var container;";
                            javascriptCode+="for(i in elements){";
                            javascriptCode+="container = document.createElement('div');";
                            javascriptCode+="parent = elements[i].parentElement;";
                            javascriptCode+="parent.replaceChild(container, elements[i]);";
                            javascriptCode+="container.appendChild(elements[i]);";
                            javascriptCode+="container.setAttribute(\"style\",\" white-space: nowrap; background-color: #EEEEEE;  padding-top: 4px;  padding-right: 4px;  padding-bottom: 4px;  padding-left: 4px;\");}";
                            webView1.loadUrl(javascriptCode);
                        }
                    }
            );
            webView1.loadDataWithBaseURL("", String.valueOf(doc), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

This is the html code I am trying to parse.

```
<h2>Checking Data Features</h2>
<h3>Get the names of the columns of an object</h3>
<p><code><strong>names</strong>(salary_data)</code></p>
<p><code>&gt; names(salary_data)</code> <code>[1] "First_Name" "Last_Name" "Grade" <br />[4] "Location" "ba" "ms"</code></p>
<h3>Compactly display the internal structure of an R Object</h3>
<p><code><strong>str</strong>(salary_data)</code></p>
<p><code>&gt; <strong>str</strong>(salary_data)</code></p>
<p><code>'data.frame': 12 obs. of 6 variables:</code></p>
<p><code>&nbsp;$ First_Name: Factor w/ 12 levels "Aaron","Adela",..: 4 3 10 5 9 11 1 8 12 7 ... <br />&nbsp;$ Last_Name : Factor w/ 12 levels "Brown","Chavan",..: 1 12 5 6 8 2 3 7 4 10 ... <br />&nbsp;$ Grade : Factor w/ 2 levels "GR1","GR2": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ... <br />&nbsp;$ Location : Factor w/ 2 levels "DELHI","MUMBAI": 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 ... <br />&nbsp;$ ba : int 17990 12390 19250 14780 19235 13390 23280 13500 20660 13760 ... <br />&nbsp;$ ms : int 16070 6630 14960 9300 15200 6700 13490 10760 NA 13220 ...</code></p>
<p>Structure gives the following information:</p>
<ul>
<li>Type of the variable.</li>
<li>Number of levels of each factor.</li>
<li>Some values of the first few rows</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to add a border, background-color and padding to the code tags in my html. But this code does not add the required style to my html content.I am displaying this content in android web view.Is there a way to add all the code tags inside a div and then style the div.

My output looks something like :-
[image]

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the style using javascript. Add the following code before `webView1.loadDataWithBaseURL(...)`

```
webView1.setWebViewClient(
    new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            String javascriptCode = "javascript:";
            javascriptCode+="var elements=document.querySelectorAll(\"code\");";
            javascriptCode+="var parent;";
            javascriptCode+="var container;";
            javascriptCode+="for(i in elements){";
            javascriptCode+="container = document.createElement('div');";
            javascriptCode+="parent = elements[i].parentElement;";
            javascriptCode+="parent.replaceChild(container, elements[i]);";
            javascriptCode+="container.appendChild(elements[i]);";
            javascriptCode+="container.setAttribute(\"style\",\"overflow:scroll; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #EEEEEE;  padding-top: 50px;  padding-right: 30px;  padding-bottom: 50px;  padding-left: 80px;\");}";
            webView1.loadUrl(javascriptCode);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: This works  but it adds style to each and every line inside the code tag.Can I add the style to the entire code block instead.

Comment: Could you add  an example for the html structure? That would simplify the process.

Comment: Please check my updated question I have also added a screen shot for clarity.Thank you.

Comment: see updated answer: wrap the code in a new element (here for example a div) and apply style to new element. Tested with so, seems to be working. Had to add `overfolw:scroll` though.

Comment: I want padding-right to be the length of the string.How can I achieve that? I tried using this code but it did not work for me javascriptCode+="container.setAttribute(\"style\",\" white-space: nowrap; background-color: #EEEEEE;  padding-top: 4px;  padding-right: elements[i].length;  padding-bottom: 4px;  padding-left: 4px;\");}";

Comment: @AndroidNewBee: please post images of the current state and the target state.

Comment: Please check the updated question for code and image. The expected output would consist of the grey area till the end of the string plus 4px.

Comment: I have one more problem. When the orientation changes the size of the text also increases. Is there a way by which the size of the text will remain same regardless of the orientation change.

Comment: @AndroidNewBee without knowing the source of your data, that is not that easy to answer. Some parent tag has probably a fixed width. For example on SO class "post-text" sets `width: 660px`, romve that and the code tag shows in the content width. So you should have a look at your source, find the parent with the limiting width and remove it. Personally I think `overflow:scroll` is the better option, though.

Comment: I have also put the html code that I am trying to display.

Comment: @AndroidNewBee: CSS is also needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123341/discussion-between-androidnewbee-and-f-klein).